# Node.js https does not work in Cloud9

Tags: node.js, https, connect, cloud9-ide

I can create an http server and it works fine, but as soon as I try to use https instead, the server runs without errors but I cannot connect to it at all.

HTTP (working):

```
http.createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

HTTPS (not working):

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

There are no errors in either method, but when I use HTTPS, there is no response when visiting the webpage and the server acts like it's not even receiving a request. Is there something wrong with the port I'm using from the Cloud9 environment? I have tried for hours to figure out what the problem is but haven't made any progress, hopefully someone can help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid HTTPS will currently not work on Cloud9, as this requires the usage of other ports that are currently not opened for security reasons. We're working on a solution for this, but this will not be available on the short term yet.

For now, I recommend using two sets of configuration for development and production environments: the development environment can then just use HTTP, and production environments can use HTTPS.

Please keep an eye on our Twitter feed and blog for updates on this!